# Scale the GKE PODs using Kubernetes API - Java Client

Tags: java, api, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have tried setting the replica count of a GKE POD using Kubernetes API. But I was getting some exceptions which I will attach below.

So, I wanted to know whether Kubernetes API is compatible to use with Google Kubernetes Engine.

I was getting some exceptions like

```
io.kubernetes.client.extended.kubectl.exception. KubectlException: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: at 
io.kubernetes.client.extended.kubectl.Kubectl$ApiClientBuilder.refreshDiscovery (Kubectl.java:235) at 
io.kubernetes.client.extended.kubectl.KubectlGet $KubectlGetSingle.execute(KubectlGet.java:108) at
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxySCglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint (CglibAopProxy.java:793) at 
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxySCglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) at
.....
```

The reference I have followed : https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/docs/kubectl-equivalence-in-java.md#kubectl-scale

For testing purpose, I am trying to just get the PODs details

```
V1Deployment pod = null;
try {
pod = Kubectl.get(V1Deployment.class).namespace("something").name("something-pod").execute();
} catch (KubectlException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

On printing `((ApiException)KubectlException.getCause()).getResponseBody()`

I am getting the below logs, I am not sure why the user is anonymous provided the user in config file is a service account.

```
{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure", "message": "forbidden: User "\system: anonymous\" cannot get path \"/api\"", "reason":"Forbidden", "details":{},"code": 403}
```

Can anyone help me in this case? Let me know if I need to clarify the question more.
Thank you

Comment: GKE is just Kubernetes. So the API's are the same. Where are you running that code ? Is it inside the cluster or outside ? And can you attach the full error

Comment: @boredabdel - I have updated the details, which will help you suggest me correct solution. Please look into this

Comment: I am trying to access PODs inside a cluster @boredabdel

Comment: That sounds like an authn issue. You need to configure the pod you run the code inside with the proper RBAC rules so it can make a call to the API Server

Comment: @boredabdel - Yes, I added the proper RBAC and now I am. getting 'service unavailable'  as a response body for KubectlException